# How can I fix the flutter ios build error

Tags: ios, flutter

I make flutter app for iOS and build, but pop up some build error like below.

```
Running pod install...                                             10.1s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         8.6s
Xcode build done.                                           173.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): unable to open dependencies file (/Users/username/Dev/appname/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources/.d)
Encountered error while building for device.
```

I find the .d file but it is not at the directory.

What is the error and how can I fix it?

I use Xcode ver. 15 (beta develop)
And iOS 12

Flutter clean
Flutter build iOS

Above commands do not work for me.